# PHP foreach loop with array table

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, html-table

How do I change it into table form with three headings which are: Company name (ABC and XYZ), Branch (Kuching and Sibu for both companies respectively), and Staff name (for both companies according to the array). I'm a beginner. Please help as I'm stuck. Something's wrong with my code.

```
<html>
<style>
</style>

<body>
<?php

$v_company= array(
    'ABC'=>array('Kuching'=>array('Michael', 'Jenny'), 
                'Sibu'=>array('Sally', 'Muhammad', 'Mutu')
                ),
    'XYZ'=>array('Kuching'=>array('Lucy', 'Abdullah'), 
                'Sibu'=>array('John', 'Alicia')
    )
);




?>

<table>

<tr><th>Company's Name</th>
    <th>Branch</th>
    <th>Staff's Name</th>
</tr>

<?php

foreach($v_company as $v_company_name=>$v_company_info){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "$v_company_name <br>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";


    foreach($v_company_info as $v_branch=>$v_staffs){

                echo "<td>";
                echo "$v_branch <br/>";
                echo "</td>";


        foreach($v_staffs as $v_staff){
                echo "<td>";
                echo "$v_staff <br/>";
                echo "</td>";
            echo "Company: ". $v_company_name. ",Branch: ". $v_branch. ",Staff: " .$v_staff . "<br>";
        }


    }   

}

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this in replacement of your deeper foreach `foreach($v_staffs as $v_staff){ echo "<td>" . implode("<br />", $v_staff) . "</td>"; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```
<html>
    <style>
    </style>
    <body>
        <?php

$v_company= array(
    'ABC'=>
        array('Kuching'=>array('Michael', 'Jenny'), 
             'Sibu'=>array('Sally', 'Muhammad', 'Mutu')
                ),
    'XYZ'=>array('Kuching'=>array('Lucy', 'Abdullah'), 
                'Sibu'=>array('John', 'Alicia')
    )
);





?>
<table>

<tr><th>Company's Name</th>
    <th>Branch</th>
    <th>Staff's Name</th>
</tr>
<?php
$company = '';
$branch = '';
$staff = '';
foreach($v_company as $v_company_name=>$v_company_info){
    foreach($v_company_info as $v_branch=>$v_staffs){
        foreach($v_staffs as $v_staff){
              echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td>";
                        if($company == '' || $company != $v_company_name){
                            $company = $v_company_name;
                            echo "$v_company_name <br>";
                        }

                  echo "</td>";
                  echo "<td>";
                        if($branch != $v_branch){
                            $branch = $v_branch;
                            echo "$v_branch <br>";
                        }

                  echo "</td>";
                  echo "<td>";
                      echo "$v_staff <br/>";
                  echo "</td>";
              echo "</tr>";  
         }
    }    
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can copy paste if you want. Happy coding

Comment: if($branch != $v_branch){

Comment: what does that do, the not equal to part

Comment: I have taken three such variables, which are initialized to empty value, I am saving current value in those variable, if same it wont print anything, else it will print.

Comment: this block only works when there will be new value for v_branch not for repeat values, same for company value too

Answer (score 0):

I updated your foreach loop echo value's try this:

```
<?php

foreach($v_company as $v_company_name=>$v_company_info){

        $rowcount = 0;    

    foreach($v_company_info as $v_branch=>$v_staffs){

        echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>";
              echo ($rowcount == 0 )? $v_company_name :  "";
          echo "</td>";

          echo "<td>";
            echo "$v_branch <br/>";
          echo "</td>";

          echo "<td>";


        foreach($v_staffs as $v_staff){
                echo "$v_staff <br/>"; 
        }
          echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
        $rowcount +=1;
    }  

}

?>
```

Is this your desired Output?

[image]

Comment: What is your desired output, show me in table format

Comment: I have updated the output image, is this your desired output? tell me.

Comment: i put in in one answer below, sorry if its troublesome

Comment: it's okay, i have added new image below my answer is the right?

Comment: Try it tell me your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get all the employees in separate rows

```
<html>
<style>
</style>
<body>
<?php

$v_company= array(
    'ABC'=>array('Kuching'=>array('Michael', 'Jenny'), 
                'Sibu'=>array('Sally', 'Muhammad', 'Mutu')
                ),
    'XYZ'=>array('Kuching'=>array('Lucy', 'Abdullah'), 
                'Sibu'=>array('John', 'Alicia')
    )
);
?>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr><th>Company's Name</th>
    <th>Branch</th>
    <th>Staff's Name</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($v_company as $v_company_name=>$v_company_info){  
    foreach($v_company_info as $v_branch=>$v_staffs){  
        foreach($v_staffs as $v_staff){
          echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "$v_company_name";

                echo "<td>";
                echo "$v_branch <br/>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo "$v_staff <br/>";
                echo "</td>";
            echo "Company: ". $v_company_name. ",Branch: ". $v_branch. ",Staff: " .$v_staff . "<br>";
             echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
        }
    }   
}

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```