# how to make this php chrismas tree blink with diff colours using css

Tags: html, css

This is a code which will produce an output like a christmas tree. How do make it blink with different colours using css. Im a beginner, thanks a lot. I was given an assignment to make it blink.

```
<?php

    $i="*";
    $row = 4;
    for($k = 0; $k <3;$k++){
        for($j=1; $j<=$row; $j++){
            echo "<center>$i</center>";
            $i .="**";
        }
        $i="*";
        $row++;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Christmas is over, why now? You're a little late ;-) btw, did you try anything?

Comment: *"I was given an assignment to make it blink."* - That's "your" assignment, not "ours"; try something. The question is too broad.

Comment: PHP is server side, CSS isn't very dynamic, so I don't foresee this working without javascript.

Comment: I think Santa is not here otherwise he might fulfill your wish.

Comment: Did you plug it in? Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: @ka_lin *lmho!* maybe on a timer also.

Comment: If the PHP builds the tree and you aren't having issues with that dont include it. Include the generated HTML and your CSS/javascript attempts to get this to blink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Following CSS and HTML Code.It can blink and change Colour Automatically

```
<style>
.blink {
  animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

p{
    -webkit-animation: color-change 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: color-change 1s infinite;
    -o-animation: color-change 1s infinite;
    -ms-animation: color-change 1s infinite;
    animation: color-change 1s infinite;
    margin-top:-10px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color-change {
    0% { color: red; }
    50% { color: blue; }
    100% { color: red; }
}
@-moz-keyframes color-change {
    0% { color: red; }
    50% { color: blue; }
    100% { color: red; }
}
@-ms-keyframes color-change {
    0% { color: red; }
    50% { color: blue; }
    100% { color: red; }
}
@-o-keyframes color-change {
    0% { color: red; }
    50% { color: blue; }
    100% { color: red; }
}
@keyframes color-change {
    0% { color: red; }
    50% { color: blue; }
    100% { color: red; }
}
</style>

<?php

    $i="*";
    $row = 4;
    for($k = 0; $k <3;$k++){
        for($j=1; $j<=$row; $j++){
            echo "<center class='blink''><p>$i</p></center>";
            $i .="**";
        }
        $i="*";
        $row++;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Please don't write code for users who haven't even made an effort themselves. This is an _assignment_, probably homework, that _the OP is supposed to do themselves_. Giving them the answer to copy and paste doesn't do much to encourage learning, does it? A better answer would be to explain a bit about CSS animation and give a _basic_ example, then let the OP apply that knowledge to the tree problem.

Comment: Yah Good way, Sorry for the Direct Answer, Hereafter I will follow. Thanks

Comment: and the OP ran off with your answer just as they did for their other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/41361266/ - Food for thought: always check their track record first before giving your free time to someone, who we would hope they'd be thankful for.

Comment: I just woke up,  and no I did not did not copy any of the code since I don't understand stand any of it.  Sorry if it seem that way,  I'm quite new to this site and programming.  I appreciate all the answers.  I'll try to do it myself.

Comment: Yah, I didn't explain every line of code for your need, I think, you can understand this simple code with some practical examples.

Comment: Do you put css code  outside php tag or inside? (final question)

Comment: I did my own css code with my teacher's help

Comment: Outside the PHP Tag, Or You can simply put in a CSS file and link that file with it.

Comment: OK thanks man,  just trying to learn:)

Comment: @user7349376 If is it correct for your need, then accept my answer, thank you